# Instagram comment breaking Community Guidelines

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to post a comment via the Instagram API on a specific picture, and I get the following error:

```
APIInvalidParametersError
Your comment goes against our Community Guidelines.
```

I have tried the following:

- Posting another comment using the same account, to another users picture. Works fine.
- **Posting the exact same comment using another account, to another users picture. Works fine!!**

So it seems that the comment itself or the posting account isn't where the problem lies, but with the account receiving the comment.

The rules for a comment are the following according to [the developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#post_media_comments) (and I do not break any of them):

> - The total length of the comment cannot exceed 300 characters.
> - The comment cannot contain more than 4 hashtags.
> - The comment cannot contain more than 1 URL.
> - The comment cannot consist of all capital letters.

I have no idea what it is in this particular case that goes against the Community Guidelines, and I have no idea on how to find out what it is.

Has anybody experienced anything similar and knows a solution?

*Unfortunately I can't show you the actual comment since it is actually a client trying to post it, and it might contain some sensitive information.*

Comment: hi @Joel, did you find any solution?, i'm also getting the same problem

Comment: @rak No, I never figured out what the problem was. I think that it somehow got caught in Instagrams spam filters. The posting account was relatively new, didn't have many posts, posting to an account with lots of followers. So I think Instagram somehow mislabeled it as spam.